# Finding All Possible Solutions with Linear Programming in R (Rglpk?)

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-programming

I'm comfortable with finding optimal solutions using Rglpk in R, however, what I'm struggling to find a solution for is generating all possible solutions that meet a minimum criteria value.

For example, for the basic dataframe below, I can use Rglpk to find the optimal total result of 1 male and 1 female.

```
df<-data.frame(c("John","Sandy","James","Sharon"),c("M","F","M","F"),c(84,70,13,62))
colnames(df)<-c("Name","Sex","Result")

df
    Name Sex Result
1   John   M     84
2  Sandy   F     70
3  James   M     13
4 Sharon   F     62

library(Rglpk)
num <- length(df$Name)
obj<-df$Result
var.types<-rep("B",num)
matrix <- rbind(as.numeric(df$Sex == "M"),as.numeric(df$Sex == "F"))
direction <- c("==","==")
rhs<-c(1,1)
sol <- Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = obj, mat = matrix, dir = direction, rhs = rhs,types = var.types, max = TRUE)

df[sol$solution==1,]
   Name Sex Result
1  John   M     84
2 Sandy   F     70
```

However, if I want to find all possible solutions or 'combinations' of that dataframe where the combined result of 1 male and 1 female score exceeds 140, I can't work out how to generate this solution and subsequently format in the following fashion

```
     M      F Result
1 John  Sandy    154
2 John Sharon    146
```

Would appreciate any help that people can offer up.

Comment: If your problem is sufficient ly small you could enumerate all possible solutions and then check each for feasibility. Using the fact that there must be exactly two 1s:  `na.omit(t(combn(1:4, 2, function(x) if (all(rowSums(matrix[, x]) == rhs)) x else NA)))`

Comment: This is the way I've gone and I'm finding it to work quite well. Haven't tested the limit with regards to number of combinations yet though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following algorithm for that:

1. Solve MIP
2. If infeasible: STOP
3. Add a constraint to the model that forbids the current optimal solution.
4. Go to step 1.

The constraint in step 3 can look like:

```
sum(i, a(i)*x(i)) - sum(i, (1-a(i))*x(i)) <= sum(i, a(i)) - 1
```

where `a(i)` is the current optimal solution (found in step 1). I.e. **a(i) = x<sup>*</sup>(i)**. The `a`'s are constants here. Note that the number of constraints grows by one in each cycle (so the model becomes larger and larger).

Here is the derivation of this cut: [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2011/10/integer-cuts.html).

It looks like you still need to add a constraint that makes sure the score exceeds 140.